# Service does not stops on calling stopService()

Tags: android

I have created a `Service` in my Android application which is working fine. But I want to stop it (completely killed) when I click `stopButton`. For this I have written this code, but this code does not stops the service when I click `stopButton`. So please help.

**Service**

```
public class HelloService extends Service {

    static boolean isRunning  = false;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        isRunning = true;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
                    try{Thread.sleep(3000);}catch(Exception e){}
                    Log.e("Update", i + "", new Exception());
                }
            }
        }).start();
        return Service.START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        isRunning = false;
        stopSelf();
    }

}
```

**MainActivity**

```
Button startButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.start);
startButton.setOnClickListener(this);
startButton.setOnClickListener(
    new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent startServiceIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, HelloService.class);
            startService(startServiceIntent);
        }
    }
);


Button stopButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.stop);
stopButton.setOnClickListener(this);
stopButton.setOnClickListener(
    new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent stopServiceIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, HelloService.class);
            stopService(stopServiceIntent);
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: My understanding is  that you need to interrupt/kill/stop that thread yourself

Comment: Your code looks fine, how are you verifying that the service is not stopped?

Comment: the loop inside `onStartCommand()` does not stops on calling `stopService()`. @jimmy0251

Comment: You shouldn't be calling `stopSelf()` in `onDestroy()`. Instead, you should be terminating your `Thread` there.

Answer (score 0):

I think you misunderstand Thread and Service.

After you `new Thread(new Runnable() {}).start();`, the stuff inside the Runnable is running in another thread, so it won't be stop if the caller stopped.

If you need a internal service timer, create a default handler instead of new thread.

Answer (score 0):

In-order to stop your thread you need to call the `Thread.interrupt()` method inside in your `onDestroy` but to do this you must have a global reference from that thread because it is inside in your `onStartCommand`. Upon calling the iterrupt an exception will be thrown and from that `catch block` we will end the lifespan of your Thread immediately.

To better understand what I am saying:

```
public class HelloService extends Service {

    Thread ref;
    boolean isInterrupted = false;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        ref = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(3000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        if (isInterrupted) {
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        ref.start();
        return Service.START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        isInterrupted = true;
        ref.interrupt();
    }

}
```